# My defined UserControl cause crash on VS2019

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create an user control with the code below, and every time I add it to my Main form, VS go crash without any trace or exception

The problem started when I try to insert:

```
[Browsable(true)]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
[Category("u4sSearchBox")]
```

But I removed it and the problem still there

I have tried delete bin, obj and .vs folder but no use
I have tried to swtich to VS2017 but no use

MethodHolderBasic.cs

```
    public partial class MethodHolderBasic : UserControl
    {
        public Bitmap ExpandedImgage;
        public Bitmap CollaspedImage;
        public bool Expanded
        {
            get
            {
                return Expanded;
            }
            set
            {
                Expanded = value;
                if (Expanded)
                    pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(ExpandedImgage, 22, 22);
                else
                    pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(CollaspedImage, 22, 22);
            }
        }
        public MethodHolderBasic()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pbDelete.Image = new Bitmap(pbDelete.Image, 22, 22);
            pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(pbExpand.Image, 22, 22);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have an exception it will be useful to look at the stack trace to understand exactly where the problem occurs. Please [edit] this info into your question

Comment: @Steve I would be thankful if the program tell me the exception or any trace, but nothing happen. When ever I drag tho control to my form, VS just crash

Comment: You are using the Expanded property as the returned value in Expanded's getter and setting it in the setter. That causes a stackoverflow problem...

Comment: If you *expand* the Getter/Setter, use a backing field (`private bool expanded`). if you do this: `Expanded = value;` you trigger the Setter. Instead: `this.expanded = value;`, `return this.expanded;`

Comment: From the code it doesn't seem you are setting Expanded Image and CollaspedImage which will cause a ArgumentNullException exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Expanded property as the returned value in Expanded's getter and setting it in the setter. That causes a stack-overflow problem so your program will crash.

Another problem (maybe not): from the code it doesn't seem you are setting Expanded Image and CollaspedImage which will cause a ArgumentNullException exception.

This code works for me:

```
public partial class MethodHolderBasic : UserControl
{
    public Bitmap ExpandedImgage;
    public Bitmap CollaspedImage;

    bool _expanded = false;
    [Browsable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [Category("u4sSearchBox")]
    public bool Expanded
    {
        get
        {
            return _expanded;
        }
        set
        {
            _expanded = value;
            if (_expanded)
                pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(ExpandedImgage, 22, 22);
            else
                pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(CollaspedImage, 22, 22);
        }
    }

    public MethodHolderBasic()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pbDelete.Image = new Bitmap(pbDelete.Image, 22, 22);
        pbExpand.Image = new Bitmap(pbExpand.Image, 22, 22);

        // Initialize ExpandedImgage and CollaspedImage
        ExpandedImgage = new Bitmap(pbDelete.Image, 22, 22);
        CollaspedImage = new Bitmap(pbExpand.Image, 22, 22);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I haven't run this code yet, just drag it in to main form. So what trigger the setter at that time?

Comment: The designer uses the Expanded property getter. When you add a property to a UserControl, it is visible in the properties window (under Misc by default) so it has to read the value

Comment: Let me check again, I think your explanation may explained every trouble I got today

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.